# How to install ibm-java-sdk-7.1-2.0-x86_64-archive.bin on OS X 10.10.1

Tags: java, macos

I was wondering if anyone knows if it possible to install the following version of the jvm on OS X 10.10.1:

IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 7 Release 1, Service Refresh 2 Fix pack 0

The name of the package that I downloaded is the following:
ibm-java-sdk-7.1-2.0-x86_64-archive.bin

The error that I get if I try to install is:

Diegos-MacBook-Pro:Downloads diego$ ./ibm-java-sdk-7.1-2.0-x86_64-archive.bin

Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

./ibm-java-sdk-7.1-2.0-x86_64-archive.bin: line 2506: /tmp/install.dir.19329/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
./ibm-java-sdk-7.1-2.0-x86_64-archive.bin: line 2506: /tmp/install.dir.19329/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: Undefined error: 0

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The installer you are trying to use is for Linux systems, not Mac OS X.

IBM's Java SDK is not available for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

http://maclord.ozarweb.com/mevzu/install-java-on-mac-lion/

Go there ^
then figure out the correct install prerequisites, and how to finalize the instillation and so forth.  However you cannot install that version specifically to OS X, that is for Linux

Answer (score 0):

Some brave internal developers did try compiling IBM Java for Mac OS X. It was painful... but it did work. Unless you manage to get a hold of source and re-compile, you're out of luck.

Comment: Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: You need access to the source for IBM's JVM and since its proprietary and a clean-room implementation of JVM spec, the source isn't available, unlike OpenJDK/HotSpot